# Why does my "Try" always fall into the "Success" when trying to match?

Tags: scala, playframework, pattern-matching

My objective find a valid "crew" where user passes in a key in the route. If the crew is found, we will try to find the actor/supervisor and tell it to START. In the code, I purposely gave the wrong actor path so it will throw the "ActorNotFound" exception. I was expecting it to match "Failure(failure)" so I can return a bad request; but it keeps falling into "Success". Why is that?

Code:

```
def index = Action.async {
    val crewType = "x"
    Future(Crew.findCaptainByCrewType(crewType)).flatMap(_.fold(
      Future(BadRequest(s"Invalid crew name provided: $crewType; will not run."))
    )(crew =>
      Future(Try(system.actorSelection(s"/user/${crew.cptName}randomness").resolveOne().map {actorRef =>
        actorRef ! "hi hi"
      }) match {
        case Success(success) =>
          Logger.info("success")
          Ok("success")
        case Failure(ex) =>
          Logger.error("failure", ex)
          BadRequest("failure")
      }
    )))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolveOne()` returns a `Future` which is kind of an async version of `Try`, you shouldn't wrap it in Try because what you do inside is creating a  new `Future` that always works. This Future will be just completed with exception.

Also avoid creating async `Future` for something that would return immediately, use `Future.successful` for this e.g.

```
Future.successful(BadRequest(s"Invalid crew name provided: $crewType; will not run."))
```

This will return already completed `Future` without scheduling it anywhere.

Here is the code that should do what you wanted

```
def index = Action.async {
  val crewType = "x"
  Future(Crew.findCaptainByCrewType(crewType)).flatMap(_.fold(
    Future.successful(BadRequest(s"Invalid crew name provided: $crewType; will not run."))
  )(crew =>
    system.actorSelection(s"/user/${crew.cptName}randomness").resolveOne().map {actorRef =>
      actorRef ! "hi hi"
      Logger.info("success")
      Ok("success")
    }.recover {
      case ex: ActorNotFound =>        
        Logger.error("failure", ex)
        BadRequest("failure")
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: and a little about Future.successful.